# Power series confusion when multiplying fractions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, convergence-divergence, power-series

I am stuck on the following question.

check that the following sum from 0 to infinity converges using power series.

sum of

$$ 1/((n+(1/2))^2)$$

the next line of work is :

$$4/((2n+1)^2)$$

I have tested values on a calculator and they prove to be the same , however why is the numerator multiplied by 4, and the denominator multiplied by 2 ?

Also why is this used ? and how does the user know to use power series from looking at the question ?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\dfrac1{\left(n+\dfrac12\right)^2}=\dfrac1{\left(\dfrac{2n+1}2\right)^2}=\dfrac{2^2}{\left(2\cdot\dfrac{(2n+1)}2\right)^2}$$

$$=\dfrac4{(1+2n)^2}=4(1+2n)^{-2}$$

See the [Conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series#Conditions_for_convergence) for convergence

Comment: Thank you for your effort, however I cannot understand the working behind the second and third part . The numerator is multiplied by 4, so the denominator must also be multiplied by 4 , however I would think ((2n+1/2)^2) * 2 = (2n+1)^2, then *2 again would give (4n+2)^2.. Can you explain where it is I am going wrong please ?

Comment: I'm awfully sorry, between the current second and third line, the denominator has been multiplied by 2, and the numerator has been multiplied by 4, how is this so ?